# Почему не получается взять из модели то,что мне нужно(просто программа прекращает работу)? Буду благодарен, если подскажите недачеты и ошибки

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


class anime(models.Model): 
    slug = models.SlugField(null = True,max_length = 10,verbose_name = "Slug")
    anime_photo = models.FileField(upload_to='media',verbose_name='Фото')
    anime_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50,verbose_name='Название Аниме') 
    anime_raiting =  models.CharField(null=True,max_length = 5,verbose_name='Рейтинг') 
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Все аниме'
        verbose_name = 'Аниме'

class Comments(models.Model): 
    anime_name = models.ForeignKey(anime,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name = 'Название Аниме',blank = True,null = True,related_name='Comments_anime')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name = 'Автор комментария',blank = True,null = True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,verbose_name='Дата написания')
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Текст Комментария')
    def __str__(self) :
        return self.date
    class Meta: 
        verbose_name_plural = 'Все комментарии'
        verbose_name = 'Комментарий' 


class AnimeSeasons(models.Model): 
    anime_name = models.ForeignKey(anime,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name = 'Название Аниме',blank = True,null = True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null = True,max_length = 10,verbose_name = "Slug")
    season_num =  models.CharField(null = True,max_length = 3,verbose_name='Номер сезона')
    season_photo = models.FileField(upload_to='media',verbose_name='Фото',blank = True,null = True)
    season_raiting =  models.CharField(null=True,max_length = 5,verbose_name='Рейтинг') 
    description = models.TextField(null = True,blank = True,verbose_name='Описание')
    class Meta: 
        verbose_name_plural = 'Все сезоны'
        verbose_name = 'Сезон' 

class AnimeSeries(models.Model): 
    anime_season =  models.ForeignKey(anime,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name = 'Название Аниме',blank = True,null = True)
    slug_season = models.SlugField(null = True,max_length = 5,verbose_name='Номер сезона')
    series_num = models.CharField(null = True,max_length = 50,verbose_name='Номер Серии')
    link = models.CharField(max_length = 50,verbose_name='Ссылка на плеер') 
    class Meta: 
        verbose_name_plural = 'Все серии сезона'
        verbose_name = 'Серия'
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView,CreateView,DetailView
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from .models import anime,AnimeSeasons,AnimeSeries,Comments
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView,LoginView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .forms import AuthUser,RegisterForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login 
from .forms import UserCommentsForm


class StartpageCreateView(ListView):
    model = anime 
    template_name = 'sitepage/sitepage.html' 
    context_object_name = 'all_anime'

class SeasonViewClass(DetailView): 
    model = anime
    slug_field = 'slug'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'
    template_name = 'sitepage/season.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_seasons'
    query_pk_and_slug = True

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SeasonViewClass, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['season_inf'] = AnimeSeasons.objects.filter(slug = self.get_object().slug)
        return context

    def get_success_url(self): 
        print(self.get_object().slug)
        return reverse_lazy(self.get_object().slug)

class SeriesViewClass(CreateView): 
    model =  anime
    template_name = 'sitepage/series.html' 
    slug_field = 'slug'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'
    form_class = UserCommentsForm

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(anime, slug = self.get_object().slug)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SeriesViewClass, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['season_inf'] = AnimeSeasons.objects.filter(slug = self.get_object().slug).filter(season_num = self.get_object().season_num)
        context['season_series'] = AnimeSeries.objects.filter(slug_season = self.get_object().season_num)
        return context

    def get_success_url(self): 
        print(self.get_object().season_num)
        return reverse_lazy(self.get_object().slug)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path,include 
from .views import StartpageCreateView,LogoutUser,SeriesViewClass,AuthUserClass,RegisterUserClass,SeasonViewClass

urlpatterns = [
    path('',StartpageCreateView.as_view(),name = 'sitepage'),
    path('logout/',LogoutUser.as_view(),name = 'logout'),
    path('auth/',AuthUserClass.as_view(),name = 'Auth'),
    path('register/',RegisterUserClass.as_view(),name = 'Register'),
    path('<slug:slug>/',SeasonViewClass.as_view(),name='SeasonPage'),
    path('<slug:slug>/<slug:slug_season>',SeriesViewClass.as_view(),name='SeasonPage'),
]
```

Comment: Что конкретно вы делаете и что конкретно ожидается? После какого действия она прекращает работу? Отображаются ли print'ы, расставленные в коде вокруг места прекращения работы?

Comment: Подписываюсь под комментарием сверху. Трудно дать совет по исправлению ошибки, когда ошибки просто нет.

Comment: При данном коде,при загрузке страницы с сериями,программа просто вылетает.При изменении в SeriesViewClass model = SasonsViewClass , программ выдаёт или лишние серии, или ошибку(MultipleObjectsReturned at /onepunch/1
get() returned more than one AnimeSeasons -- it returned 2!)

Comment: @andreymal,принты работали.Просто скорее всего я не очень понимаю,как работать с моделями в классах DetailView и CreateView.